# Generate a fancy PDF certificate from form?

Tags: forms, files

Anyone have ideas on how to generate a fancy PDF certificate in drupal based on user-supplied form input? Here's an example of what I want to do here:

http://www.infiniteskills.com/cert/01596

This form just collects a name and build a nice PDF. Not sure if the email address is used for anything (other than perhaps collecting email addresses).

I've attached a screenshot of the final PDF so you can see the result without using the form.

Thanks for any ideas or pointers.[image]

Edit: Adding a link the Drupal certificate module: http://drupal.org/project/certificate

This module requires the print module and seems a little heavy for what I'm trying to do. Also, as far as I can tell, it will only create a PDF from existing HTML page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a proper fillable PDF form and then use the [Fill PDF](http://drupal.org/project/fillpdf) module to merge it with data from a node or a webform.

Have a look at the demo on the [Fill PDF service website](http://try.fillpdf-service.com/).

Comment: tostini - cool, thanks. I think that might work. Will take a look.

Comment: tostini - PDF fill is awesome - thanks for the pointer. I'm testing it with webform and webform_token, and it's a piece of cake to map the webform fields to the form fields in the PDF. Works great. How do I close this question?

Comment: Glad to see it helped you. To "close" the question accept it by clicking the tick beyond the arrows and points on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [Certify](http://drupal.org/project/certify) in the Related Projects right sidebar of Certificate module you linked !?

It sounds leaner.

Comment: tenken - thank you. I looked at that a few weeks and completely forgot about it. The readme makes it look like book and quiz modules are dependencies but it doesn't appear that way on the project page. I'll take a look. Certify is probably a useful starting point either way.

Comment: Tenken - PDF fill is awesome - thanks for the pointer. I'm testing it with webform and webform_token, and it's a piece of cake to map the webform fields to the form fields in the PDF. Works great. How do I close this question?

Comment: Put the comment in the wrong place but can't remove it so I added a new comment above.